# Using if/else statements with output from theme options

Tags: php, css, theme-options

In [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11479/using-theme-options-to-change-link-colours) I was talking about using theme options to modify CSS. This is a separate but related question.

When a user sets a link colour in my theme, here's how I'm including their choice:

```
<?php $options = get_option('mytheme_theme_options'); _e( 'a, a:link {color: #' ); echo $options['linkcolour']; _e( ';}' ); ?>
```

So, if a user specifies a link colour of #333333 in the theme options page, then my code above outputs a nice clean bit of CSS:

```
a, a:link {color: #333333;}
```

Great.

However, if they **don't** specify any link colour value, then I get this:

```
a, a:link {color: #;}
```

...which is both ugly and redundant -- it doesn't do anything.

I'm not a PHP person, so I don't really know the best way to fix this, but I imagine that it could be fixed with an if-else statement of some kind, where the code only gets output when the user sets a value. Is that right? If so, what code should I use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to be using `_e()` that's for text that's to be translated, you don't translate CSS, it only comes in one language...

With regard to your if/else'ing, try this..

```
<?php 
$options = get_option('mytheme_theme_options');
if( isset( $options['linkcolour'] ) && ( !empty( $options['linkcolour'] ) ) )   
    printf( "a, a:link {color: #%s;}", $options['linkcolour'] );
?>
```

Here's some PHP references for helping understand the PHP that was used above.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php

Hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome. :) t31os, good sir -- I thank you! Great answer.

Comment: As a related sub-question: how would I go about doing the same thing with output from other form elements -- checkboxes, radio buttons, drop-down select inputs, textareas, etc? Would the code be pretty much identical, or are there any changes?